# Unable to download files from s3 using shared aiobotocore client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiobotocore

I want to download and upload files to S3 asynchronously, and I'm using aiobotocore for that. Rather than creating a new client for every request as mentioned in the docs (which is slow), I decided to reuse the client.

I have this class

```
class S3Utils:

    def __init__(self):
        self._session = get_session()
        self._s3_client = self._session.create_client('s3', region_name=config.S3_REGION)

    async def upload_file(self, file_path):
        try:
            async with self._s3_client as s3_client:
                async with aiofiles.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                    await s3_client.put_object(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET, Key=file_path, Body=(await f.read()))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Error uploading file', exc_info=e)

    async def download_file(self, file_path):
        try:
            async with self._s3_client as s3_client:
                response = await s3_client.get_object(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET, Key=file_path)
                content = await response['Body'].read()

            async with aiofiles.open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                await f.write(content)

            return file_path
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Error downloading file', exc_info=e)
            return None

    async def download_all_files_in_directory(self, bucket, directory_path):
        try:
            files = []
            async with self._s3_client as s3_client:
                response = await s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=directory_path)
                if 'Contents' in response:
                    for file in response['Contents']:
                        file_path = file['Key']
                        if file_path.endswith(('jpg', 'png')):
                            files.append(file_path)

            results = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(self.download_file(file)) for file in files])
            
            print(f'results: {results}')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Error downloading files', exc_info=e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(S3Utils().download_all_files_in_directory('bucket-name', 'folder-name'))
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
2024-03-12T07:13:51.177643Z [error    ] Error downloading file         filename=s3_utils.py func_name=download_file lineno=38
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\src\utils\s3_utils.py", line 29, in download_file
    async with self._s3_client as s3_client:
  File "<path>\venv\lib\site-packages\aiobotocore\session.py", line 25, in __aenter__
    self._client = await self._coro
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
results: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiveing this error. Since I'm awaiting the `download_file` function as a task and not as a coroutine, this should've worked.

I tried copying the code of the `download_file` function and using it directly inside `download_all_files_in_directory` like this:

```
async def download_all_files_in_directory(self, bucket, directory_path):
        try:
            files = []
            async with self._s3_client as s3_client:
                response = await s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=directory_path)
                if 'Contents' in response:
                    for file in response['Contents']:
                        file_path = file['Key']
                        if file_path.endswith(('jpg', 'png')):
                            response = await s3_client.get_object(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET, Key=file_path)
                            content = await response['Body'].read()

                            async with aiofiles.open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                                await f.write(content)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Error downloading files', exc_info=e)
```

This worked but this looks ugly since I'm copying the code. I think the original version of this method is cleaner but I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: A workaround I found is [this](https://gist.github.com/mattwang44/0c2e0e244b9e5f901f3881d5f1e85d3a). But I still want to know why the above doesn't work.